# python - remove array column if it contains at least one 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's suppose I have a `np.array` like:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

I would like to know if there is a pythonic way to find all the columns that contain at least one occurence of 0. In the example I would like to retrieve the indexes 2 and 4.

I need to remove those columns, but I also need to know how many columns I have removed (the indexes are not strictly necessary).
So in the end I simply need the result

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply remove the columns, you can use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) (or its `ndarray`) variant to find the columns you want to keep. Use the resulting boolean mask to index the 2nd axis:

```
>>> arr[:, arr.all(axis=0)]
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

If you want to find the indices of those columns with at least one zero, you can use [`np.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) in conjunction with [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) (or [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html#numpy.flatnonzero) if you prefer):

```
>>> np.any(arr == 0, axis=0).nonzero()
(array([2, 4], dtype=int64),)
```

If you want to count them, you can sum the boolean mask directly:

```
>>> np.any(arr == 0, axis=0).sum()
2
```